# R округляет time до даты

Tags: postgresql, r

При загрузке таблицы из *PostgreSQL* (*RPostgreSQL*) *R* округляет до даты.

Вместо `2015-01-28 03:04:01 CET` имею `2015-01-28 CET`, но *Class "POSIXct" "POSIXt"*, не только показывает, но и на самом деле `2015-01-28 00:00:00 CET`.

Причем это только на локальном маке, *R* нa сервере получает ту же таблицу без проблем.

Скорее всего, какие-то настройки. Может кто помочь?

```
> command3 <- "SELECT requested_at FROM rides  WHERE  city_id != 1;"
> riders3 <- dbSendQuery(con, command3)
> riders_total <- fetch(riders3, n = -1)
> riders_total$requested_at[1]
[1] "2015-04-19 CEST"     #####    is "2015-04-19 03:04:31 CEST" !
> riders_total$requested_at[1] + 1
[1] "2015-04-19 00:00:01 CEST"
```

Comment: наверное, можно добавить метку про postgresql

Comment: Покажите `SELECT pg_typeof(requested_at) FROM rides;`.

Answer (score 1):

Надо попробовать проверить time zone при чтении. Например

```
base::format(dbGetQuery(con, command3)$requested_at, format="%Z")
```

Также нужно быть уверенным, что в PostgreSQL тип данных http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, для начала, одинаковые ли версии *R* и *RSQLite* установлены на сервере (под Linux'ом?) и на Mac'е. Лучше везде обновиться до последних версий.